# mount: Permission denied (when mounting /system directory on android device)

Tags: shell, adb, mount

**I have rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 (Int) using CynongenMod OS**. I am trying to install and run an executable file which needs its configuration file to be copied to the /system directory.

Now, after copying my files from PC to the /sdcard folder, i am unable to copy the **.conf** file to **/system/etc** and I can't also copy **.exe** file to **/system/bin**.

I know that I have to mount the **/system** directory. I restarted my phone and boot into **Recovery Mode** and then mounted **/system** directory, but it did not work.

I also tried mounting it manually from the adb shell using the following command:

```
mount -o remount wr /system/
```

still it is not mounting and I can't perform the copy. It shows me in the terminal the following message:

```
mount: Permission denied
```

so please **help me mounting the /system directory**

Comment: the command is `mount -o remount,rw /system`

Comment: @AlexP.: It worked. Would you please put your comment as an answer, thank you

Comment: Thank you @ChrisStratton for the note, and sorry for putting off-topic question .. what do you suggest I do , should I delete the question ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything - you have your answer and the question may or may not be closed by the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `mount -o remount,rw /system`